# TextField with value is considered to be empty?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone tell me why this statement validates to YES when the textbox clearly has a value?

> UITextFieldtext = 'dcxcv' clipsToBounds = YES opaque = NO;

```
if (self.entityName.text != @"") {
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: because a value like the random string @"foo" is different to @""?! And if (@"foo" **!=** @"") is true

Comment: Can you put more contradictory double negatives in your code, it is too easy to understand ;-). If something doesnt equal something then don't return something??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
if ([self.entityName.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {
}
```

With:

```
self.entityName.text != @""
```

You are testing if the pointer to text property is different from @"", which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

the approach is wrong, if you want to compare strings objective-c gives you a nice method to handle this.
instead of using:

```
if (self.entityName.text != @"") {
        return NO;
    }
```

try this:

```
if ([self.entity.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
  return NO;
}
```

the approach you have made is not recognised by objective-c is because it doesn't know what you write by mentioning this `@:""`it has to know that you are trying to compare a string. hope this helps you.